# Parse referer Request in CakePHP 3.5

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I need to parse the previous page URL to know which page I come from. I get it with :

```
$this->referer('/', true);
```

And I'm trying to use this to get informations :

```
Router::parse($this->referer('/', true));
```

But the method `Router::parse` is deprecated and will be removed in next version of cake PHP.

Then, I'm trying to use :

```
Router::parseRequest($this->referer('/', true));
```

But I get this error :

> Argument 1 passed to Cake\Routing\Router::parseRequest() must
>   implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface, string
>   given

I search a solution for long time but I don't find any solution reliable. Maybe I missed something, does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What information exactly do you need from that URL? Be aware that this wouldn't work with external URLs, as parsing will match against the connected routes!

Comment: @ndm I need to know from which controller and action I come

Comment: You could create a new `ServerRequest` object, but there's some pitfalls to this. Maybe there's a way to avoid parsing... what are you planning to use that info for?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the request object:

```
    $controller = $this->request->getParam('controller');
    $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
```

- If you cannot use it then you can do as suggested by @ndm :

```
    $referer = new \Cake\Http\ServerRequest(['url' => $this->referer()]);
    $controller = $this->request->getParam('controller');
    $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
```

- You can use getRouteCollection as suggested [here](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues/5595):

```
    Router::getRouteCollection()->parse($this->referer());
```